# API - sending data without request in some timeframe

Tags: rest

First of all, sorry for my English.

This is a more theoretical question than practical. Our client wants a REST API, that would work as a normal REST API + the API should have a function when the API would send large amounts of data to the other side in some timeframe (probably their API to sync data of tables between two companies) without them asking for the data. The timeframe should be editable. What do you think, what is the best way to solve this?
We thought about saving timeframes in a table, but then we would need to check regularly the table for changes, which is not ideal.
Do you have any other ideas or tips even for the API?
Thank you